# Migrating js file from prototype to jQuery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm migrating files from prototype to jQuery.

prototype:

```
function hideEditableMarkers() {
   $$('.edit_marker').each(function(el) {
  el.hide();
});
   $$('.show_marker').each(function(el) {
    el.show();
    });
}

Event.observe(window, 'load', hideEditableMarkers);
```

jQuery:

```
function hideEditableMarkers() {
  jQuery('.edit_marker').each(function(el){
    el.hide();
    });

  jQuery('.show_marker').each(function(el){
    el.show();
    }); 
}

jQuery(document).ready(hideEditableMarkers());
```

I don't know why it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of the each callback function is the index of the element not the reference to it

so here is the jquery code

```
function hideEditableMarkers() {
  $('.edit_marker').each(function(idx,el){
    $(el).hide(); // You may use 'this' variable in here as it points to the current element as well
    });

  $('.show_marker').each(function(idx,el){
     $(el).show();
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
jQuery(document).ready(hideEditableMarkers());
```

should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(hideEditableMarkers);
```

You need to pass the function reference to `ready` so it's executed as the callback handler for the DOM ready event. What you're currently doing is executing the function immediately (when the elements don't exist), then passing the return from that function (nothing) as the callback for `.ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this)` inside each so it takes the current element... what you have is index and use index as jquery selector `el.hide()`

try this

```
function hideEditableMarkers() {
 jQuery('.edit_marker').each(function(el){
   $(this).hide();
 });

 jQuery('.show_marker').each(function(el){
   $(this).show();
  }); 
 }

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  hideEditableMarkers() ;
});

//or

jQuery(document).ready(hideEditableMarkers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a function should be reusable:

```
/*global jQuery */

function toggleMarkers (hideSelector, showSelector) {

    jQuery(hideSelector).each(function () {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    });

    jQuery(showSelector).each(function () {
        jQuery(this).show();
    });

}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    toggleMarkers('.edit_marker', '.show_marker');
});
```